# jQuery Datepicker: Show one date format to user, use another date format in the background

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-format

I've got an input using the datepicker tool from jQuery. Now I know I can set the date format being used by the datepicker. Problem is: I'd like to show the date in the german format to the user, while using the english format for the database (dd-mm-yy to yy-mm-dd).

What I have here now is the following:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $("#test").html($.inst.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dateText); // What exactly do I have to do, to get the date from dd-mm-yy to yy-mm-dd
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to use $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', dateText) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably your best option is to use `altField` and `altFormat` properties for the datepicker, which are there exactly for this reason: [API Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField).

If you set the altField to an hidden input field, you can then get the data from there when uploading to the DB or for anything else you need the alternate date format.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion gonna try that!

Answer (score 2):

I use this for the form field:

```
echo 'Set next action date: <input type="text" id="next_action" name="next_action" value="' . $next_action . '" />';
```

In the scipt setup for datepicker I include this option:

```
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
```

That gives me proper MySQL date format to insert/update in the table. But it's not particularly friendly to visitors, so I set up my preferred format at the top of the page:

```
if ($s['next_action'] >= "1") {
    $next_action = date($date_style,strtotime($s['next_action']));
} else {
    $next_action = '';
}
```

That depends on a variable in my master include file:

```
$date_style = "F d, Y";
```

If I pick a date, datepicker gives me a good date for the database on submit, although it shows the yyyy-mm-dd format until it's submitted. After submitting, it uses the pretty display.

Van

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, unfortunately that's a php solution (which I'm not using for this project). Thanks anyway :)